# C++ Interpreter: How to emit error messages?

Tags: c++, string

I want to emit dynamic error messages like all interpreters do nowadays, for example:

```
Name error: Undefined variable
```

would be constant, however what I want to reach is:

```
Name error: Undefined variable 'X', in line 1
```

Okay. The line number was really no problem: Every error message must have a line number, so I added it to the error emitter function:

```
Error( ErrType type, string msg, int line );
```

**So where is my problem?**

How do I get the `'X'` into `Undefined variable *`?

- I can't use sprintf as it doesn't support strings yet I use them everywhere
- I can't simply use cout and connect everything as I want error messages to be supressable
- I'd like to get everything into one function like above, `Error()`

**How do I put together dynamic error messages?**

For example: `Error( Name, sprintf("Undefined variable %s", myVariableName ), lineNum );`

(But `myVariableName` is a string and `sprintf` will mess things up)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a null-terminated C string out of `myVariableName` by calling `c_str`:

```
myVariableName.c_str()
```

Note that your use of `sprintf` is incorrect; the first parameter of `sprintf` takes the buffer into which to place the formatted string.  If you are using `std::string` in your program, why use `sprintf` at all?  If `Error` takes a `std::string` then you can just use string concatenation:

```
Error(Name, "Undefined variable " + myVariableName, lineNum);
```

Comment: Holy cow, I didn't know that you can simply use + to concenate some strings!

Answer (score 3):

[Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) solves that by having their diagnostics have `operator<<` overloaded, streaming the required arguments, which I adopted in my compiler too

```
DiagnosticBuilder Error( ErrType type, string msg, int line );
```

You can then call it like

```
Error(Serious, "Variable % is not known", lineNumber) << var;
```

When the diagnostic-builder's destructor is called, the error is emitted.

```
struct DiagnosticBuilder {
  DiagnosticBuilder(std::string const& format)
    :m_emit(true), m_format(format) 
  { }
  DiagnosticBuilder(DiagnosticBuilder const& other) 
    :m_emit(true), m_format(other.m_format), m_args(other.m_args) {
    other.m_emit = false;
  }
  ~DiagnosticBuilder() {
    if(m_emit) {
      /* iterate over m_format, and print the next arg 
         everytime you hit '%' */
    }
  }

  DiagnosticBuilder &operator<<(string const& s) {
    m_args.push_back(s);
    return *this;
  }
  DiagnosticBuilder &operator<<(int n) {
    std::ostringstream oss; oss << n;
    m_args.push_back(oss.str());
    return *this;
  }
  // ...
private:
  mutable bool m_emit;
  std::string m_format;
  std::vector<std::string> m_args;
};
```

I find that this way of doing it is quite convenient. You can extend it to support multiple languages by numbering the argument placeholders, like `"Variable %2 isn't found in scope %1"`.

Comment: +1, That's a neat idea. I personally didn't like instantiating a diagnostic object, so I opted for a singleton logger that exposes its own `operator<<`. I may revisit that in the future.

Comment: +1:  I just implemented something very similar to this and it works very nicely.  Thanks for the idea.