# How to create a type-tag for template specialization

Tags: c++, templates, global-variables, template-specialization

I have a custom logging class that supports `iostream`-syntax via a templated `operator <<`:

```
template< class T >
MyLoggingClass & operator <<(MyLoggingClass &, const T &) {
    // do stuff
}
```

I also have a specialized version of this operator that is supposed to be called when a log-message is complete:

```
template< >
MyLoggingClass & operator <<(MyLoggingClass &, consts EndOfMessageType &){
    // build the message and process it
}
```

`EndOfMessageType` is defined like this:

```
class EndOfMessageType {};
const EndOfMessageType eom = EndOfMessageType( );
```

The global constant `eom` is defined so that users can use it just like `std::endl` at the end of their log-messages. My question is, are there any pitfalls to this solution, or is there some established pattern to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you seen http://www.templog.org? It solves a similar problem through template-meta programming. Templog decided that relying on users to provide an EOM token is too error-prone. Thus, a message is logged automatically at the end of the full expression: `blah << foo << bar;`.

Comment: @sbi: unfortunately, that solution means you cannot construct a message in a loop

Comment: It's not a global variable, because it's const. That's just a constant.

Comment: I can't remember having needed this but, yes, this uncommon case is a bit harder. But the very common case of having to log a message built all in one line is much easier this way. (You can still pre-build a message in a loop and pass this to a log statement, if you want.) This way you can't forget to pass an EOM token, resulting in an important message not logged, because it was still cached when your system crashed.

Answer (score 2):

`std::endl` is a function, not an object, and `operator<<` is overloaded for accepting a pointer to a function taking and returning a reference to `ostream`. This overload just calls the function and passes `*this`.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Let's end this line now";
    std::endl(std::cout); //this is the result of cout << endl, or cout << &endl ;) 
}
```

Just an alternative to consider.

By the way, I don't think there is any need to *specialize* the operator: a normal overload does just as well, if not better.

Comment: I have never understood why the stream library uses function pointers, though, instead of function objects. But that's probably [also just for historical reasons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222131/why-does-stdbasic-ios-overload-the-unary-logical-negation-operator)...

Answer (score 0):

I think your solution is acceptable. If you wanted to do it differently, you could create a class `Message`, that would be used instead of the your `MyLoggingClass` and provided automatic termination.

```
{
  Message m;
  m << "Line: " << l; // or m << line(l) 
  m << "Message: foo"; // or m << message("foo");
  log << m; // this would automatically format the message
}
```

Comment: I thought about this, but this would require three lines of code for even the simplest log-messages (and the simple ones are far more frequent than the complex ones).

Answer (score 0):

I have done it [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662554/c-interpreter-how-to-emit-error-messages/2662619#2662619), like some other people did. Have a function `Error` / `Log` / `Warning` / etc that could look like this

```
DiagnosticBuilder Error( ErrType type, string msg, int line );
```

This will return a temporary builder object, whose class is basically defined like

```
struct DiagnosticBuilder {
  DiagnosticBuilder(std::string const& format)
    :m_emit(true), m_format(format) 
  { }
  DiagnosticBuilder(DiagnosticBuilder const& other) 
    :m_emit(other.m_emit), m_format(other.m_format), m_args(other.m_args) {
    other.m_emit = false;
  }
  ~DiagnosticBuilder() {
    if(m_emit) {
      /* iterate over m_format, and print the next arg 
         everytime you hit '%' */
    }
  }

  DiagnosticBuilder &operator<<(string const& s) {
    m_args.push_back(s);
    return *this;
  }
  DiagnosticBuilder &operator<<(int n) {
    std::ostringstream oss; oss << n;
    m_args.push_back(oss.str());
    return *this;
  }
  // ...
private:
  mutable bool m_emit;
  std::string m_format;
  std::vector<std::string> m_args;
};
```

So if you are building a log message in a loop, be it so

```
DiagnosticBuilder b(Error("The data is: %"));
/* do some loop */
b << result;
```

As soon as the builder's destructor is called automatically, the message is emitted. Mostly you would use it anonymously

```
Error("Hello %, my name is %") << "dear" << "litb";
```